# How to add output to a windows form application using c# and visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

http://www.question-defense.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/intel-945gm-driver.gif

how to create an application which displays output which i want the user to see ? (like the above image)
I tried using list box but i am having issues with dynamically updating it.

Comment: Show the code you have so far

Comment: I have tried list box but it does not update !!
i tried labels but i did not like it doing it that way !!
I could get the progressbar to update but not the lextboxes or listboxes or array of labels etc.

Comment: I found this solution that helped me accomplish that: https://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a RichTextBox, and call RichTextBox.AppendText() when you need to output text to it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/3tdc88y7.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i did that but the speed at which its displaying text is not enough.
i mean i want the output box to show log at each second or minute etc. so it has to be accurate and not print a bunch at a time.

Comment: currentrly i am using rich text box and "frame.doevents()" to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You can show the output in the TextBox control, for it you will need to set the textbox's property Multiline = true